# Unsupported subreport section type ArrayList in jaspersoft

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I need to show a complex report that takes data from beans.

I've created a container bean, that has got the List of other beans.

```
public class OreComputateContainerBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    private Long id; 

    private List<ViewOreGiorniMeseTotBean> listViewOreGiorniMeseTotBean;
    private List<ViewOreComputateMeseBean> listViewOreComputateMeseBean;
    private List<ViewOreComputateBean> listViewOreComputateBean;
}
```

In the main report on Tibco Jaspersoft, I add subreports and I create a field like

```
<field name="listViewOreGiorniMeseTotBean" class="java.util.List"/>
```

the subreport is built as follows:

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="171" height="83" uuid="a0bfc3a5-e452-4f3e-a875-2eaaf7f367e6"/>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$F{listViewOreGiorniMeseTotBean}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

When I try to build the report in my application, I see the following exception

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Unsupported subreport section type java.util.ArrayList
```

How do I need to build the subreport to have data shown correctly?

Comment: 1) The `subreportExpression` is for setting report (subreport) for show at main report, not for passing datasource. 2) The datasource can't be passed as just a List, it should be an implementation of `JRDataSource` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your subreport definition:

1. `subreportExpression` should define the path to subreport `.jasper` file
2. data reference should be passed as `dataSourceExpression`. Moreover JasperReport require subreport data source to be instance of JRDataSource.

So one of the possible solutions is to modify subreport declaration to something similar to

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="171" height="83" uuid="a0bfc3a5-e452-4f3e-a875-2eaaf7f367e6"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listViewOreGiorniMeseTotBean})]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[subreport_path_relative_to_SUBREPORT_DIR_variable.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```